Why are some literary universes called "Cycles"?
There are some literary series or universes that are called "cycles", like Peter Watt's Sunflower Cycle, or Ursula K. Le Guin's Hainish Cycle.
Where does this naming convention come from? Was there maybe a notable first cycle, which other authors are following? Does it have a special meaning that makes it different from calling something a "series"?

"People write me nice letters asking what order they ought to read my science fiction books in — the ones that are called the Hainish or Ekumen cycle or saga or something. The thing is, they aren't a cycle or a saga. They do not form a coherent history. There are some clear connections among them, yes, but also some extremely murky ones. And some great discontinuities (like, what happened to "mindspeech" after Left Hand of Darkness? Who knows? Ask God, and she may tell you she didn't believe in it any more.)" - https://tinyurl.com/vyd78e8y

Wagner's Der Ring des Nibelungen operas are also known as the Ring Cycle. Dunno if there's anything older than that

From Wikipedia: "A literary cycle is a group of stories focused on common figures, often (though not necessarily) based on mythical figures or loosely on historical ones."

From the online OED: "6.1835– spec. A series of poems or prose romances, collected round or relating to a central event or epoch of mythic history and forming a continuous narrative; as the Arthurian cycle.
